# FluentNhibernate Joined Class

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

With the table definition:

```
Employee
     EmployeeId Primary Key
     LastName
     FirstName

EmployeeAddress
     EmployeeAddressId    
     EmployeeId
     Address
     City
```

And class definition of

```
public class Employee
{
     public int EmployeeId {get; set;}
     public string LastName {get; set;}
     public string FirstName {get; set;}

     public EmployeeAddress EmployeeAddress {get; set;}
}
```

What type mapping should be used to populate Employee.EmployeeAddress.  My first attempt was

```
Reference(x=>x.EmployeeAddress).Column("EmployeeId")
```

that generates the join as

```
Employee.EmployeeId = EmployeeAddress.EmployeeAddressId
```

Can I use Join to do it?  Something like

```
Join("EmployeeAddress", join => join.Map(x => x.EmployeeAddress).
```

That generates an error when configure is called.  It seems I can only use Join for individual properties and not the class.  I can get Join to work if I add properties in the Employee class for Address and City and then map those, but I want to map it as a class not each individual property.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the Fluent syntax (for `one-to-one` it's `HasOne` and for `many-to-one` it's `References`), but this is the resulting XML:

```
<class name="Employee">
  <id name="EmployeeId">
    <generator class="..." />
  </id>
  <property name="FirstName" />
  ...
  <one-to-one name="EmployeeAddress" cascade="all" property-ref="Employee" />
</class>
<class name="EmployeeAddress">
  <id name="EmployeeAddressId">
    <generator class="..." />
  </id>
  <property name="Address" />
  ...
  <many-to-one name="Employee" column="EmployeeId" unique="true" cascade="all" />
</class>
```